# characteristic equation's solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the characteristic equation for $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$  $$\lambda = -e^{-\tau\lambda}\tag1$$
a) For $\lambda$ a root of (1), write $\lambda = x+iy$ and consider the real and imaginary part of (1). Rewrite (1) as a system of two equations. 
b) Show that if $\lambda$ is a solution to (1) then $\bar\lambda $ is also a solution to (1). 
I did the first part:
\begin{cases} x= -e^{-\tau x}\cos(\tau y) \\ y= e^{-\tau x}\sin(\tau y) \end{cases}
I really need help for the second part.

Comment: It seems obvious: if $(x,y)$ satisfies both equations, $(x,-y)$ does too.

Comment: @Bernard Yes I agree it's obvious that $\bar  \lambda$ satisfies the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$${\lambda} = -e^{-\tau{\lambda}}$$
$$ {\lambda} = -e^{-\tau x}(\cos (y\tau)-i\sin (y\tau))$$
$$\bar {\lambda} = -e^{-\tau x}(\cos (y\tau)+i\sin (y\tau))$$
$$\bar {\lambda} = -e^{-\tau x}e^{iy \tau}$$
$$\bar {\lambda} = -e^{-\tau (x-iy)}$$
$$\bar {\lambda} = -e^{-\tau \bar {\lambda}}$$
If $\lambda $ is a solution, so is $\bar {\lambda }$. You can read [this page too](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Exponential_Form_of_Complex_Conjugate)

---

Or more simply.
$${\lambda} = -e^{-\tau{\lambda}}$$
Change $ \lambda  \to \bar {\lambda}$
$$\bar {\lambda} = -e^{-\tau \bar {\lambda}}$$